# Can I add a conditional "pre" task to a pyinvoke task?

Tags: python, pyinvoke

[pyinvoke](http://pyinvoke.org) supports so called "pre" tasks, that have to be executed before running a task:

```py
@task(pre=[required_precondition])
def mytask(c, param1=False):
    pass
```

Is it possible to add a condition to a "pre" task (i.e. run "required_precondition" only if param1 is True)?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I have seen no, the pre and post conditions are created at "compile time", which means they won't have access to a parameter. Alternatively, it is part from perfect,
but you can use the fact that you can call one task from another (it is not explained in the docs) to manually do your pretask condition.

```py
from invoke import Collection, task

@task
def hello(c):
    print("hello")

@task
def goodbye(c, a=False):
    if a:
        col = Collection()
        col.add_task(hello)
        col['hello'](c)

    print('goodbye')
```

Outputs

```sh
> invoke goodbye
goodbye

> invoke goodbye -a
hello
goodbye
```

It does feel "hacky", but as far as I can this is the easier way.

Note:
If for any reason your tasks are already part of a `namespace` or `ns` variable,
you don't need to create a new collection, just call them from the namespace itself as in
`namespace['hello'](c)`

Comment: Instead of creating a collection, adding a task and call it, one could also call the task directly: "hello(c)".
But in both cases deduplication does not work, which is an essential part of invoke.